# How to call ToBindingList() only for one type in the table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, binding

I got table  consiting of `Person`,`Client`,`Employee` I would like to bind `Employee` instances to the `BindingList<Client>` not to `BindingList<Person>`. Is it possible? `Client` and `Employee` derive from `Person`.

Now I do this:

```
context.People.OfType<Client>().Load();//DbContext
BindingList<Person> Clients = context.People.Local.ToBindingList();
```

but this way I loose access to `Client` properties. Also I load all of them: `Person`,`Client`,`Employee` and I want only Clients.

Comment: You don't really lose access to `Client` properties since you can cast if you know it's a `Client` (or use `as` and a null check). I'm not sure what you're trying to do since it seems like your code snippet contradicts your first sentence.

Comment: @jjj It contradics because it is not solution but  the faulty code. I want load only clients. `.TypeOf(Client).Load()` will load them all(it just does it).

Comment: what's the inheritance relationship between each of the classes?

Comment: @jjj `Client` and `Employee` derive from `Person`.

Answer (score 1):

If the context doesn't have a property `Clients` you can always use

```
context.Set<Client>().Local.ToBindingList();
```